# Async custom validator not working and showing error message in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-observable

I am new to Angular 8 and trying to create custom async validator. Below is my code:

In my typescript file I am creating form field like below. I am using only async validator(no sync validator so passing 'null' as second parameter):

```
group.addControl(control.Name, this.fb.control('', null, this.phoneValidator));
```

Below is my async validator code:

```
phoneValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    if(control.value == '' || control.value == undefined || control.value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return this.phoneValidatorServiceCall(control.value)
        //.pipe(map((data: any) => {
        //  return (data.Response == "True" ? null : { phoneValidator: true });
        //}))
        .subscribe(data => {
            return (data.Response == "True" ? null : { phoneValidator: true });
        })
      }
   }
```

In above code I tried to use "Pipe" only it's not working so used "Subscribe" only but even this not working. Below is my service method:

```
phoneValidatorServiceCall(input): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post<any>('http://xxxxxxxx:xxxx/validate/phone', { 'Text': input });
}
```

For showing error in html I am using below code:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input #dyInput [formControlName]="Phone" matInput [placeholder]="Phone" [required]="IsRequiredField">

<!-- For showing validation message(s) (Start) -->
<mat-error *ngFor="let v of Config.Validators">
  {{ f.controls['Phone'].invalid }} // comes true only on error
  {{ f.controls['Phone'].hasError("phoneValidator") }} // always coming false even for wrong input
  <strong *ngIf="f.controls['Phone'].invalid && f.controls['Phone'].hasError('phoneValidator')">
    {{ My Message Here }}
  </strong>
</mat-error>
<!-- For showing validation message(s) (End) -->
```

I am facing two problems:

1. It's not waiting for response from service. Somehow it's always return error from phoneValidator(control: AbstractControl) method
2. Error message not showing on screen. f.controls['Phone'].hasError("phoneValidator") always coming false

Comment: for general anything you want to make `aysnc await` you have to use your function as `async validationFunction() { await  this.data = this.serviceCall() }`

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to subscribe in your validator. You should only return the observable. Something like this: `return this.phoneValidatorServiceCall(control.value).pipe(...)`

Comment: Thanks @GaurangDhorda for reply. can you please provide some example.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGătej for reply. I tried with only pipe but its not working.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hwcff this stackblitz link may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been given good tips on how to solve your problem. Those gathered... So your current issues are:

Add return type of validator:

```ts
Observable<ValidationErrors | null>
```

Since that is what you are going to return.

So don't subscribe in the validator, instead return the observable. Also, you need to `return of(null)` when valid, since again... we need to return an observable. So modify your validator to:

```ts
import { of } from 'rxjs';

//....

phoneValidator(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
  if (!control.value) {
    return of(null);
  } else {
    return this.phoneValidatorServiceCall(control.value)
      .pipe(map((data: any) => {
        return (data.Response == "True" ? null : { phoneValidator: true });
      }))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AJT82 but still every time it's returning false.

Comment: so is `data.Response == "True"` ever truthy? Have you checked that? What does `console.log(data)` produce? Also `f.controls['Phone'].invalid` might be wrong if you are doing `[formControlName]="Phone"`.

Comment: data.Response comes "True" when phone number is validate else it returns "False". Response is correct but f.controls['Phone'].invalid is always true. That is problem

Comment: `f.controls['Phone'].invalid` is then actually a formcontrol, right? Your form looks like: `this.f = this.fb.group({Phone: ''})`? Please provide a [mcve] it's really hard to help otherwise, but I suspect it should be `f.controls[Phone].invalid`

Comment: Here's a working sample, which always returns error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9k5qp-pd7ju3?file=app/input-overview-example.html Please fork the stackblitz and reproduce the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems -

1. The return type of `phoneValidator` should be `Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null>`.
2. Do something like below so that you return an observable and check if your second problem gets solved -

> return observableOf({ phoneValidator: true });

3. Use pipe and map your response.